# Limit of derivatives and asymptotes relation

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Prove if the following statements are either true or false:

1. If an asymptote exists for $f$ (when $x \to \infty$) with slope $m$ and if the limit  $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f'(x) = L$ exists,then $L = m$.
2. If $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f'(x) = m$ , $m \in \mathbb{R}$, $m \neq 0$ then $f$ has an asymptote with slope $m$.

I've successfully verified that statement one is true.  However,I'm pretty much stuck at statement two.  If anyone could shed a light on how to begin the second statement proof I would be deeply grateful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: look for counterexamples to #2 where $m=0$.